# Where is appengine:appengine-maven-plugin 1.8.2?

Tags: google-app-engine, maven

When running `mvn appengine:devserver` using version 1.8.2 of com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin, I get the following message.

```
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/appengine/appengine-maven-plugin/1.8.2/appengine-maven-plugin-1.8.2.pom
[WARNING] The POM for com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:jar:1.8.2 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:1.8.2: Plugin com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:1.8.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:jar:1.8.2
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/eclipse/m2e/lifecycle-mapping/1.0.0/lifecycle-mapping-1.0.0.pom
[WARNING] The POM for org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:jar:1.0.0 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:1.0.0: Plugin org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:1.0.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:jar:1.0.0
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml (12 KB at 268.9 KB/sec)
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml (22 KB at 317.6 KB/sec)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.350s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Jul 19 15:57:02 EDT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/16M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'appengine' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\atrupe\.m2\repository), central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
```

I get no errors when using 1.8.1 and 1.8.1.1. Should I have another repository listed in my pom?

Comment: looks like this got resolved. https://code.google.com/p/appengine-maven-plugin/issues/detail?id=32

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an issue that is localized in time

Comment: Thanks for filing an issue. Looks like this is still not resolved.

Comment: So strange. I'm still hitting the issue. I'm using the "com.google.appengine.archetypes:guestbook-archetype" and I've changed appengine.target.version to 1.8.2. 1.8.1 and earlier work. But with 1.8.2 I get "$ mvn appengine:devserver
... 
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:1.8.2: Plugin com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:1.8.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:jar:1.8.2"

Comment: @amir can you link to your pom? I just did mvn dependency:purge-local-repository and then appengine:devserver and got no errors.

Comment: Sure Antony. Thanks for taking a look at this. "mvn dependency:purge-local-repository" failed similarly and had no effect. Link to pom: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/tzx7qg4iegyevyj/dgXQ_BfWkr/myapp/pom.xml
 ; Link to app (guestbook archetype with appengine.target.version as 1.8.2): https://www.dropbox.com/sh/tzx7qg4iegyevyj/obYizwOXZh

Comment: @amir interesting. I wonder if your maven install is mucked up.

Comment: So you have no issues with the app I put on dropbox? It's strange that the issue only happens with appengine 1.8.2 and that 1.8.1 works fine. I'm wondering if some libraries on my machine are creating the difference. It's hard to believe there is a maven setup issue that is exposed by app engine version 1.8.2.

$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.0.4
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.7.0_25, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.5.0-37-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

Comment: I tried installing maven 3.0.5 and hit the same issue. I updated the app-engine issue you filed with a detailed stack dump. I'm very surprised that I'm the only one hitting this issue...

Answer (score 0):

I am using 1.9.10 and it is working all well.

```
<dependencies>...
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
    <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
 </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
 <plugins>...
  <plugin>
     <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
     <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
  </plugin>
 </plugins>
</build>

<properties>...
   <appengine.target.version>1.9.10</appengine.target.version>
</properties>
```